# getting jHipster project working with Atomikos JTA/XA transactions

Tags: jhipster, atomikos

I've been playing with the jHipster yeoman generator for the past week and I'm trying to get my application working with atomikos for JTA/XA transactions and I'm running into a number of problems, which is to be expected since I'm new to spring boot and a number of the other components in the jHipster stack.

I have been using the example found [here](http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2014/04/15/distributed-transactions-multiple-databases-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-atomikos/) as my starting point for configuring atomikos.  I've implemented everything described there, replacing HikariCP entirely.

At the moment I have eliminated Metrics and liquibase from my configuration as they were giving me problems and I wanted to get the basics working and then add them back in.  However, I'm now hitting a Hibernate issue.

Hibernate is complaining that second-level cache is used but hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given.  The factory_class setting is specified in the configuration and I'm not able to figure out what I'm missing.

Has anyone managed to get atomikos (or maybe bitronix) working with this stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working.  For some reason I had to explicitly set hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache to false.  Not sure why it would require this given that I am not setting any second level cache flags anywhere that I can see.

Never the less.  It's working now.